# TypeError while iterating through a Hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following hash:

```
{
  "groups" => [
    {
      "type" => "Nearby", 
      "venues" => [
        {
          "id" => 4450132, 
          "name" => "Position2", 
          "address" => "Domlur", 
          "city" => "Bangalore", 
          "state" => "Karnataka/India", 
          "zip" => "560037", 
          "verified" => false, 
          "geolat" => 12.9566921, 
          "geolong" => 77.6407258, 
          "stats" => {
            "herenow" => "0"
          }, 
          "twitter" => "position2", 
          "hasTodo" => "false", 
          "distance" => 0
          },...
```

I want to iterate through it and find all the 'name' attributes. My code looks like:

```
response["groups"]["Nearby"]["venues"].each do |key|
  logger.debug key['name']
end
```

But I keep on getting error:

```
TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):
```

I am on ruby 1.9.

Comment: I tried with - response["groups"]["venues"].each do |key|, also but got the same error

Comment: Your sample Hash is not valid; The braces and brackets are not balanced. It *REALLY* helps when you provide valid data, even if it's a subset of the real data. Also, for large data structures please use some vertical space in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I clean up the hash so it's properly balanced:

```
data = {
  "groups" => [
    {
      "type" => "Nearby",
      "venues" => [
        {
          "id" => 4450132,
          "name" => "Position2",
          "address" => "Domlur",
          "city" => "Bangalore",
          "state" => "Karnataka/India",
          "zip" => "560037",
          "verified" => false,
          "geolat" => 12.9566921,
          "geolong" => 77.6407258,
          "stats" => {
            "herenow" => "0"
          },
          "twitter" => "position2",
          "hasTodo" => "false",
          "distance" => 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can iterate over the hash finding the `'name'` keys using:

```
data['groups'].map{ |i| i['venues'].map{ |j| j['name'] } } # => [["Position2"]]
```

Because the data is nested, the resulting extracted data will be nested. To flatten it use `flatten`:

```
data['groups'].map{ |i| i['venues'].map{ |j| j['name'] } }.flatten # => ["Position2"]
```

Answer (score 3):

`response["groups"]` is an Array. Arrays are indexed by integers, not strings.

If you want to get the group, whose type is "Nearby" you can use:

```
response["groups"].find {|h| h["type"] == "Nearby}["venues"].each ...
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
response["groups"][0]["venues"].each do |key|
 logger.debug key['name']
end
```

The reason is that your response["groups"] object is actually an array and not a map.

Comment: Since he tried to use "Nearby" as the key, I'm assuming he wants to get the group whose type is "Nearby", not necessarily the first group. Though admittedly the problem description is too vague to tell for sure.

Comment: Sure but from what i saw he had trouble internalizing the difference between a map and an array and how they are arranged in his data structure. I think that once he is able to tell the difference it will be able to solve him problem quickly.